# Inequality for hook numbers in Young diagrams

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, integer-partitions, young-tableaux, algebraic-combinatorics

Consider a Young diagram $\lambda = (\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_\ell)$.  For a square $(i,j) \in \lambda$ define *hook numbers* $h_{ij} = \lambda_i + \lambda_j' -i - j +1$ and *complementary hook numbers* $q_{ij} = i + j -1$.  Let
$$H(\lambda) = \prod_{(i,j) \in \lambda} h_{ij}\,, \qquad
Q(\lambda) = \prod_{(i,j) \in \lambda} q_{ij}\,.
$$

**Question:** is there an elementary proof of the following inequality:
$$H(\lambda) \le Q(\lambda).
$$

For example, when $\lambda = (3,2,1)$ we have 
$$H(\lambda)=5\cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 1\cdot 1 \cdot 1 = 45, \qquad
Q(\lambda)=1\cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 3\cdot 3 \cdot 3 = 108.
$$
Let me mention that 
$$\sum_{(i,j) \in \lambda} h_{ij} = \sum_{(i,j) \in \lambda} q_{ij},
$$
so somehow this says that $q_{ij}$ are more evenly distributed.

**Note:** this inequality is a corollary of the main results in [our paper](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/papers/excited.pdf).  The proof of the main result is algebraic and quite involved.

**UPDATE** (7/7/2016)
Cross-posted on MO where it was [resolved](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/243846/inequality-for-hook-numbers-in-young-diagrams).

Comment: I think belongs on mathoverflow.net.